# c# looping method in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, stopwatch

I am sure this may have been answer somewhere but I have searched all over the web and cannot find an obvious solution?

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (stopwatch.IsRunning == false)
    {
        stopwatch.Start();

        while (stopwatch.IsRunning == true)
        {
            label7.Content = stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString();
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

label7 does not update and I am assuming its because the while loop never exits?

but I also tried this with no joy?

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (stopwatch.IsRunning == false)
    {
        stopwatch.Start();
    }

    label7.Content = stopwatch.Elapsed.ToString();
    Thread.Sleep(1000);

    button5_Click(sender, e);
}
```

Comment: doing `Thread.Sleep()` in the UI thread is going to freeze your application. You need to either use a `DispatcherTimer` or put your code in a `Task` or something.

Comment: The second is also an endless loop.  What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

You don't want to do a Thread.Sleep(1000) in there.  That will make it so that the UI won't be able to update itself.  Instead, use a timer and when the timer tick event fires, change the text in the label.

So for your example, when you define the stopwatch, define its interval and then add an event handler for the 'Tick' event.  When it 'ticks' set the content of your label.

Use a DispatcherTimer so that you don't have to shift to the UI thread, as your timer will work within the UI thread for you.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are creating a timer class, you should use the Timer Elapsed event.  Update your UI in there.

[MSDN Timer Elapsed Event Description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed.aspx)

As has been said, sleeping your process thread will essentially freeze the application.  Generally avoid it if you can unless you have a very specific reason to sleep a thread.  1 second is also an eternity for a computer, so your elapsed time increments should be relatively small.  A user will notice 1 second, they will have a harder time notice increments of .1 s and less.